# How to check if Texture 2D was provided in shader graph?

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I have following section in my shader graph, that I want to simplify. At the moment I have to set manual boolean **Use Normal Map** in order to decide if I want to use a **Normal Map** texture or default **Normal vector**. Ideally, I want to figure out a way to change this and detect if **Normal Map** was provided: if yes go to **Sample Texture 2D** step, if not use default **Normal Vector**. This way getting rid of that manual boolean.

I tired checking for null, but I can't seem to be able and plug in normal map into that.

[image]